# php post method is not working correctly

Tags: php

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "KyleLongrich", "Cash7144") or die('could not connect to server');

mysqli_select_db($con,"kylelongrich") or die("could not connect to database");


if(isset($_POST['Send']))
{

$Firstname = strip_tags($_POST['firstname']);
$Lastname = strip_tags($_POST['lastname']);
$Email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$Topic = strip_tags($_POST['topic']);
$Message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO emailquestions (Firstname, Lastname, Email, Subject, Message) VALUES ('$Firstname','$Lastname','$Email','$Topic','$Message')";

mysqli_query($con, $sql);

echo $FirstName;

}

?>

<div class="contact-forum">

    <form action="Test2.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="FirstName"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="LastName"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="topic" placeholder="Topic"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="message"> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="Send">
    </form>
</div>
```

It gives me this error:

"Notice: Undefined variable: FirstName in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\Test2.php on line 22"

line 22 is referring to "echo $FirstName;"

I have been staring at this for hours any help would be great.

Answer (score 4):

(insert obligatory comment about SQL-injection-vulnerability here)

PHP is case sensitive.

```
$Firstname
```

is not the same as

```
$FirstName
```

Comment: naah. happens to me all the time. it's just a matter of experience to think of those possibilities first.